# len() function shows 45 values as opposed to 90 values which it should, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: python, string, list, int

Here is the code I have which is using the txt file to make a list, which is being printed fine, showing that it contains 90 values:

```
read_txt = open("Data.txt", "r")

my_list = read_txt.readlines()

for values in my_list:
    if not values.startswith("#"):  # ignores the header comment in the text file
        values = values.rstrip("\n") # strips \n from end of each value

        print(values)

read_txt.close()

print(len(values))
```

However the `print(len(values))` is giving 45.

Comment: I don't understand the question. When I write  a = [1,2,4,'b','c']; len(a);   This gives "5".  No TypeError.  Can you give a more concrete example of what you're doing?

Comment: @jubba Please add some code to your post so that we could understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: "I realise this is because there is int and string values" no, absolutely not. `len` does not care about the types of objects in your list You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Provide some sample data and your code in order to make your question more specific.

Comment: I realised what i was doing wrong and have now got the len() to give me a value, however the value should be 90 and it is returning 45.

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation that the len([1,2,'a','b']) would not give you the count of elements in your list is if you have a class that redefined __len__ function. Check in your class if you have

```
  def __len__(self):
      #defined differently
```

Else the issue is elsewhere:)